# Authentication with Shiro on Zeppelin : principal argument cannot be null

Tags: ldap, apache-zeppelin, shiro

I want to configure my Zeppelin to make an authentication to my AD with ldap. I've configured in conf/shiro.ini following informations :

```
ldapRealmExtern = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm
ldapRealmExtern.contextFactory.url = ldap://authentication.mycompany.com:389
ldapRealmExtern.contextFactory.systemUsername = CN=user,OU=XX_Func,OU=XX_Users,OU=XX_ACC,OU=XX,DC=xx,DC=FR
ldapRealmExtern.contextFactory.systemPassword = ******
ldapRealmExtern.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = simple
ldapRealmExtern.authorizationEnabled = true
ldapRealmExtern.userSearchBase = dc=xx,dc=FR
#ldapRealmExtern.userSearchFilter = (&(cn={0})(objectclass=organizationalPerson))
ldapRealmExtern.userSearchFilter = cn={0}
ldapRealmExtern.userObjectClass = organizationalPerson
ldapRealmExtern.userSearchAttributeName = cn
ldapRealmExtern.groupObjectClass = group
ldapRealmExtern.memberAttribute = member
ldapRealmExtern.groupSearchBase = dc=xx,dc=FR
ldapRealmExtern.groupSearchFilter = member={0}
ldapRealmExtern.memberAttributeValueTemplate=cn={0},OU=XX_Intern,OU=XX_Users,OU=XX_ACC,OU=XX,DC=xx,DC=FR
```

When I start Zeppelin, I can make a login, but following exception is thrown :

```
 WARN [2020-12-03 06:16:56,887] ({qtp1580893732-92} ModularRealmAuthenticator.java[doMultiRealmAuthentication]:224) - Realm [org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm@33f9f341] threw an exception during a multi-realm authentication attempt:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: principal argument cannot be null.
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.SimplePrincipalCollection.add(SimplePrincipalCollection.java:104)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.SimplePrincipalCollection.<init>(SimplePrincipalCollection.java:59)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.SimpleAuthenticationInfo.<init>(SimpleAuthenticationInfo.java:93)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm.createAuthenticationInfo(LdapRealm.java:985)
        at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.DefaultLdapRealm.queryForAuthenticationInfo(DefaultLdapRealm.java:377)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm.queryForAuthenticationInfo(LdapRealm.java:268)
        at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.DefaultLdapRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(DefaultLdapRealm.java:295)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(LdapRealm.java:217)
        at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:568)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doMultiRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:219)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:269)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.AuthenticatingFilter.executeLogin(AuthenticatingFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter.onAccessDenied(FormAuthenticationFilter.java:154)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.AccessControlFilter.onAccessDenied(AccessControlFilter.java:133)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.AccessControlFilter.onPreHandle(AccessControlFilter.java:162)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.PathMatchingFilter.isFilterChainContinued(PathMatchingFilter.java:203)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.PathMatchingFilter.preHandle(PathMatchingFilter.java:178)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:131)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.server.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:411)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've also a log which say that I don't have any role :

```
 WARN [2020-12-03 06:16:56,947] ({qtp1580893732-92} LoginRestApi.java[postLogin]:206) - {"status":"OK","message":"","body":{"principal":"myuser","ticket":"cb575d5e-a170-4e5f-9160-8350b3853943","roles":"[]"}}
```

Do you have any idea of what is wrong in this configuration ? How can I get the groups with my AD ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution was to upgrade Apache Zeppelin to 0.9.0-preview2. Then the login on active directory work again.

Answer (score 0):

We also faced same error.We still getting exception , but we managed to get roles populating for user and authorization is working .We changed many properties, but The property which makes difference is :

ldapRealm.groupSearchEnableMatchingRuleInChain = true